# DTO's with Hibernate, Frontend Objects vs Backend Objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, design-patterns

I'm starting with Hibernate 4,  in a web project with AngularJS, I have a doubt about a typical case when you want to use your Entity Java Classes (Hibernate) with you GUI, In one case I need to add two fields more: Type Name and User Name to show in the frontend, but this fields are in another Tables in my Model, the Object Template has only the id (ManytoOne).

Here the Question, what is the best Practice in this case, create a DTO's or add this new field's in your class, but without mapping with the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably recommend to use DTOs. By adding the fields to the object model, you bind your model with your frontend representation and both can grow and change separately.

For the moment, you have only one view where you display this entity but it can change and if you go with 3 different views of your entities, you will have to add to your entity 3 different ways to represent it in the same object.

Some views may need few informations while others may need more informations. If all this views use the same object, all informations will be passed regardless of the needs.

I would recommend to uncouple the business model from its representations.

Comment: ok, great, and now the question, to clone the entity object to the DTO, is there any Library to simplify the process, I saw in several post's libraries like: lambdaj, dozer, Commons BeanUtils, what is your favorite for this task?

Comment: It you feel like informations will be common and shared, a good practice is to create interface to represent your DTOs. I don't know those libraries lambdaj, dozer. BeanUtils can be use to do reflections but it can be tricky when you have to refactor. Just create a class MyObjectForThisView that takes your object as parameter in constructor  and extract only the useful informations.

Comment: The most popular libraries for doing that are Orika and Dozer. I prefer using Orika (https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika) since it's very customizable, faster than Dozer and easy to use and configure and without using xml. Their guide is very clear and helpful (http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/). Also, if you want to integrate it nicely with Spring here's one way of doing it (https://github.com/dlizarra/orika-spring-integration).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using DTO's:

- The Database layer (your repositories or DAO's) gets and returns only  model entities.
- The Service layer gets and returns only DTO's.

So the Service layer is in charge of mapping DTO's into entities and viceversa.

This decouples the view from the database model and gives much more flexibility when sending data from the server to the client.

Mapping DTO's into entities generates a lot of code, but in the end it tends to pay off. You can use a library like [Orika](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika) or [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) to help you out with that.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view , I believe that it is better that you hidden your domain model ( like your entity object ) from the client side of program . As general it is better that you just access to your domain from repository , even your services can't access to your domain model objects directly . (In MVC paradigm). So at the end I think it is better you make a DTO in your server and send it to your client side

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the answer Kaveh